# Hibernate association with createCriteria and createAlias

Tags: java, hibernate, associations, criteria, alias

I have two simple mappings:

```
<class name="org.testing.Person" table="PERSON">
        <id name="personId" type="long" column="PERSON_ID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="personName" type="string" not-null="true" column="PERSON_NAME"/>
        <many-to-one name="personAddress" class="org.testing.Address" column="PERSON_ADDRESS"    not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true"/>
</class>
```

and

```
<class name="org.testing.Address" table="ADDRESS">
    <id name="addressId" type="long" column="ADDRESS_ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="street" column="ADDRESS_STREET" type="string" />
    <property name="city" column="ADDRESS_CITY" type="string" />
    <property name="state" column="ADDRESS_STATE" type="string" />
</class>
```

I try to get property of the person address like this:

```
session.createCriteria(Person.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("personName", "Frodo"))
                    .createAlias("personAddress", "pa")
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("pa.street"))
                    .list();
```

and it works.
Then like this:

```
session.createCriteria(Person.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("personName", "Frodo"))
                    .createCriteria("personAddress")
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("street"))
                    .list();
```

and it throws: `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: street of: org.testing.Person`. I assume both should give the same result. Where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using **createCriteria("personAddress")** in the second query?

Comment: I am using it because there is a property named **personAddress** in **Person** class and it is one end of the association to the **Address** class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.setProjection(Projections.property("street"))` always operates on the root criteria. To project joined items, you have to use the first version you posted.

Answer (score 9):

hibernate 3.3.2;

let us see code source :

```
 public Criteria createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType) {
    new Subcriteria( this, associationPath, alias, joinType );
    return this;
}


public Criteria createCriteria(String associationPath, int joinType) {
    return new Subcriteria( this, associationPath, joinType );
}
```

**createCriteria return sub Criteria ,so all the operation is on sub Criteria ;
but createAlias is return the criteria who create sub Criteria ;**

**example 1.** 
Ad manyToone adgroup ; all of them have " name "properties

```
     Criteria criteria1    = s.createCriteria(Ad.class, "ad").add(Restrictions.eq("ad.id", Long.valueOf(343909))) ;
     Criteria criteria2    =  criteria1.createCriteria("adGroup")
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("name"))
         List list  = criteria2.list();


    List list = s.createCriteria(Ad.class, "ad").add(Restrictions.eq("ad.id", Long.valueOf(343909)))
                    .createAlias("adGroup", "adGroup")
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("name"))
                    .list();
```

let us say the name in adgroup is " aaaa "
the name in ad is "bbbb"
in first statement  , "name" value of result is  from  adGroup entity = " aaaa ".
in second statement , "name" value of result is  from   Ad entity "bbbb" .

ps1: if there is no "name" properties in adgroup entity ,but in ad entity, first statement will throw Exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: AdGroup ;
but if u change to " .setProjection(Projections.property("ad.name")) ",it will be fine returning the value of ad's name

**ps2 :first statement call list() by criteria2 ,but hibernate will process from the root criteria = criteria1 ; so the final sql will contain " where ad.id =343909 " from criteria1 ;**

**example  2.**

[image]

teacher oneToMany student 
student oneToMany student

```
  List list1 = s.createCriteria(Teacher.class, "teacher").add(Restrictions.eq("teacher.id", Long.valueOf(343909)))
                    .createCriteria("students").createCriteria("books")
                    .list();



 List list2 = s.createCriteria(Teacher.class, "teacher").add(Restrictions.eq("teacher.id", Long.valueOf(343909)))
                    .createAlias("students").createCriteria("books").setProjection(Projections.property("name"))
                    .list();
```

second statement will throw Exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: books of: Teacher;
because books is a property of student 
**that is difference between  createCriteria and createAlias ;**